Shared user profile in QGIS
I'm using QGIS and I want to change the file path for user profiles to a shared network drive. How would I go about doing that?
I want the company to be able to access shared user profiles with different settings and templates set individually, without new coworkers needing to go through a complicated process to set it up.

This is probably a bad idea, 2+ people working with the same profile on a shared drive will almost lead to issues down the line.  Better to have a script which new users run to copy the template profile to their machine (then they can recreate it if they mess it up later).

You don't want users to share profiles. Try instead company wide customised settings https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#deploying-qgis-within-an-organization

@IanTurton Thanks for the reply! Where would I start creating a script to do this? I'm not much of a coder (at all) but I'd like to learn.
